# Titanium: UIWebView worker doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, uiwebview, titanium, worker

I am using JavaScript web worker technique inside UIWebView HTML pages to achieve background tasks in Titanium apps. It works fine on iOS but no luck on Android, I can't even figure out the error details. Here's the script code:

```
<script>

    function startWorker(){
    var worker = new Worker('/worker.js');
    // message event handler
    worker.onmessage = function (event) {
        // logging
        Ti.API.error( 'WebWorkerMessage:'+ JSON.stringify(event) );
        // update the html page - not actually needed, just for demostration should the WebView be visible
        document.getElementById('result').textContent = event.data;
        // fire a titanium app event

        Ti.App.fireEvent( "WORKER", { data: event.data } );


    };
    // error event handler
    worker.onerror = function(event){
        Ti.API.error( 'WebWorkerError:'+ JSON.stringify(event) );
    };  
    }
 </script>
```

The error handler is called as soon as this script is evaluated from my Alloy controller. I am testing this script on an Android 4.4.2 device, a log for this error is useless:

```
WebWorkerError:{"cancelBubble":false,"returnValue":true,"srcElement":{},"defaultPrevented":false,"timeStamp":1422484158088,"cancelable":true,"bubbles":false,"eventPhase":2,"currentTarget":{},"target":{},"type":"error"}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which emulator/device/os version are you testing on.

Comment: LG device, android version 4.4.2